# Inner class name not detected using hasClass in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
a=$("<div></div>").html('<div class="wow">Have a good day!!!</div>')
console.log('check if wow present?', a.hasClass('wow'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I check if class with name wow is present, in the above code my attempt to check class with name wow always comes as false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use children().hasClass

```js
a=$("<div></div>").html('<div class="wow">Have a good day!!!</div>')
console.log('check if wow present?', a.children().hasClass('wow'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The only caveat here would be that it only checks immediate children, however still a nice clean answer. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Yours is returning `false` because `.hasClass()` only works for the immediate element, not children elements.

[`$a.find(".wow").length`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will return how many times the class `.wow` occurs within `$a`, including children of children (and so on). `!!` converts this to a boolean.

In the code below, I've elected to make it a jQuery plugin so you can use `$element.anyChildHasClass("wow")` the same way you'd use `$element.hasClass("wow")`.

```js
//Create jQuery plugin
$.fn.anyChildHasClass = function(className) {
    return !!this.find("."+className).length;
};

//EXAMPLE 1: First child has class
var $a = $("<div></div>").html('<div class="wow">Have a good day!!!</div>');
console.log( $a.anyChildHasClass("wow") ); //true

//EXAMPLE 2: No child has class
var $b = $("<div></div>").html('<div>Have a good day!!!</div>');
console.log( $b.anyChildHasClass("wow") ); //false

//EXAMPLE 3: Child of a child has class
var $c = $("<div></div>").html('<div>Have a <span class="wow">good</span> day!!!</div>');
console.log( $c.anyChildHasClass("wow") ); //true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code should care of nested levels then use $().length

```js
a = $("<div></div>").html('<div class="wow">Have a good day!!!</div>')
console.log('check if wow present?', 0 < a.find('.wow').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```